# Dynamic content

Tags: php, cakephp

My index page has a two column layout. In the left I have several icons (links) and in the right the dynamic content. Every time I click in one icon of the left I would like to show related information in the right.

I don't know if I should use Ajax or something related to CakePHP (I've read about `requestAction` but I think that's not the right way).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my question.

Comment: Maybe it is not specific enough?

Comment: @mark Well, I just want to know how to load dynamic content with CakePHP when I click a button (or link). I do not know how to be more precise.

Comment: @enrmarc: Create action and view for Ajax (swich off layout), and use $.ajax from jQuery

Comment: @kicaj Thanks. So Ajax is the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know about `jQuery` and `$.ajax in jQuery`.

So you can do it this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){

        $('LINKS_LEFT').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax(
            {
                url         : href,
                dataType    : 'html',
                beforeSend  : function()
                {
                    // show loading or else
                },
                success     : function(response)
                {
                    if(response)
                    {
                        // display it in right side div.
                    }
                }
            });

        })

    });

</script>
```

Comment: cakephp.org were itself worked like this before they updated their site.

Comment: Thanks @Dipesh Parmar, but I think I'll use the `JsHelper`

Comment: using helper may effect on site performance...

Comment: http://www.chainfire.eu/articles/76/CakePHP_and_performance_for_noobs_/ read it using helper make impression of 25% of site load.

Comment: Much appreciated @Dipesh Parmar, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$this->Js->link()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3alink) to generate an ajax call.

But i suggest you start reading the whole [JsHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html) documentation.

Comment: Much appreciated. I'll do it.